# Firebase search query gives different results

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on search feature. I have list of over 2000 products in my Real-time DB.

I tried searching `Shampoo` with 3 queries. But none of the Query returns the Desired Product name with the String "Shampoo".

But `Query 1 & 2`returns Products like the below Image which doesn't have "Shampoo" in the Product name node.

I can't figure out why it happens ?

[image]

**CODE**

```
    const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('S01/Products');

    // Search Query 1 - Shows Different Product (Refer above image)
      var query = databaseRef.orderByChild("productName").startAt("Shampoo");

    // Search Query 2 - Shows Different Product (Refer above image)
      var query = databaseRef.orderByChild("productName").endAt("Shampoo");

 // Search Query 3 - Shows Different Product (Refer above image)
        var query = databaseRef.orderByChild("productName").startAt("Shampoo").endAt("~");

 // Search Query 3 - Returns no Products
      var query = databaseRef.orderByChild("productName").equalTo("Shampoo");

 // Search Query 3 - Returns no Products
        var query = databaseRef.orderByChild("productName").startAt("Shampoo").endAt("Shampoo" + "~");

      query.once("value")
        .then(function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

            var t = $('#products_table').DataTable();

            var key = childSnapshot.key;

            var MID = childSnapshot.child("productMID").val();
            var SID = childSnapshot.child("productSID").val();
            var ProductID = childSnapshot.child("productID").val();
            var name = childSnapshot.child("productName").val();
            var unit = childSnapshot.child("productUnit").val();
            var productMRP = childSnapshot.child("productMRP").val();
            var price = childSnapshot.child("productSellingPrice").val();
            var buying_price = childSnapshot.child("productBuyingPrice").val();
            var productStatus = childSnapshot.child("productStatus").val();

            var row = "";

            t.row.add(['<td class="cell-60 responsive-hide"></td><td class="cell-300">', '<td>' + name + '</td>', '<td>' + unit + '</td>', '<td tabindex="1">' + productMRP + '</td>', '<td tabindex="2">' + price + '<\/td>', '<td tabindex="3">' + buying_price + '<\/td>', productStatus]).node().id = ProductID;
          });
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A query such as this:

```
var query = databaseRef.orderByChild("productName").startAt("Shampoo");
```

will produce a list of products sorted alphabetically by `productName`, starting with the first name that *starts with* "Shampoo" or any string that alphabetically follows "Shampoo".  It does *not* require that a product have "Shampoo" in the product name.  Furthermore, it will not include products that *do* have "Shampoo" embedded in the name, if the name does not start with something that follows "Shampoo".

For example, "My Favorite Shampoo" will be excluded because 'M' < 'S'.  Any product name that starts with a letter greater than 'S' will be included, as will "Super Soap", because "Su" follows "Sh".

The Firebase API does not support queries for text "contained" in a value (SQL: `WHERE productName LIKE %shampoo%`).  More details at this [Firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html), with a link to ElasticSearch as an option for advance text searches.